# Auto adjusting using Angular drag and drop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am trying to recreate drag and drop in angular based on following - http://plnkr.co/edit/KgDKZSXNBQitLrtT1xpM

But the difference that I am getting is when I drop any list item, then those are not auto arranged.

My code -

```
<div ng-controller="projectRayController">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body container-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-sm-2" id="sidebar-wrapper">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <a id="toggle-menu">
                                <li class="list-group-item">Toggle Menu</li>
                                </a>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Create Project</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <div id="progress-board">
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                        <div class="col-md-3 task-column">
                                            <div style="border:1px solid black; height:200px;" data-drop="true" ng-model="list1" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
                                                <div class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-model="list1" ng-show="item.title" data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},animate:true}">
                                                <script type="text/javascript">alert('hi');</script>
                                                {{item.title}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 task-column">
                                            <div data-drop="true" ng-model="list2" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
                                                Drop here 2
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 task-column">
                                            <div data-drop="true" ng-model="list3" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
                                                Drop here 3
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3 task-column">
                                            <div data-drop="true" ng-model="list4" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true}">
                                                Drop here 4
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="btn btn-droppable" ng-repeat="item in list5" data-drop="true" ng-model='list5' >
                            <div data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" class="btn btn-info btn-draggable" data-drag="true" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}},placeholder:true,animate:true}" ng-hide="!item.title" ng-model="list5">{{item.title}}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('projectRayApp', ['ngDragDrop']).controller('projectRayController', function($scope, $http, $q) {
                $scope.list1 = [];
                $scope.list2 = [];
                $scope.list3 = [];
                $scope.list4 = [];

                $scope.list5 = [
                    { 'title': 'Item 1', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 2', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 3', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 4', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 5', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 6', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 7', 'drag': true },
                    { 'title': 'Item 8', 'drag': true }
                ];
            });

            $('#toggle-menu').click(function(e) {

                console.log('clicked');
                $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');

            });
        </script>
```

Can someone help me out with same as I need to understand the details of where I am going wrong.

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 0):

If you need the dropped items in the list to be sorted after dropping, then use the `orderBy` filter with your `ng-repeat` in your list. Basically you pick the item property that you wish to sort by (in your case `title`). An example for one of the lists:

```
ng-repeat="item in list1 | orderBy : 'title'"
```

This will sort the repeated list by `item.title`. I have updated your attached fiddle to show this working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4bI98pqhNQuy3UT7gzNI?p=info).

Comment: I think I was not clear, I want them auto arranged once I drop them, Which is not happening. the dropped item just stays where I dropped it and not arranged